# How can I catch the click on notification?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I need to call some methods after clicking the notification. My notification has a pendingIntent that opens a browser. But I also have to do some other things AFTER user clicks it. Oh, and I must admit that I get my notifications from GCM(push).

```
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlString));
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(mBitmap)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification myNotification = notificationBuilder.build();
        myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getBaseContext(), title, body, pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(TAG, myNotification);
```

Comment: Can you please add you notification code

Comment: @SajalChoukse code added)) can you help me please?)

Comment: What do you mean by doing "some other things AFTER user clicks it"? Do you just mean that you have to do other operations prior to launching the browser?

Comment: @SajalChoukse I need to send message using Tracker (HitBuilders) for getting some Analytics about users that clicked my notification.

Comment: Add notification flag into intent and when user comes from notification to browser activity check for that flag and if exist call those methods.

Comment: @androidnoobdev I dont know how to do this, but I'll try, thank you)

Comment: Just an idea, I don't tested but maybe helps you, create a transparent activity, on the `onCreate` method of this transparent activity make your Analytics  and then invoke your browser intent. In your notification change the intent of your PendingIntent to call your transparent activity

Answer (score 0):

To handle the click on the notification itself (not an action) you need to specify a `ContentIntent` as following:

```
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(
              context,
              0,
              new Intent(context, YourActivity.class)
                  .putExtra("extra_something", something)
                  .setData(Uri.parse("pass an uri if needed")),
              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
          ))
```

Hope it helps.